# Calculate the influence of various factors on the final change

Tags: python, pandas, math

I have a dataframe with data about price of premises.
Example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'num': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7],
                   'date': ['2024-01-01', '2024-01-01', '2024-01-01', '2024-01-01', '2024-01-01', '2024-01-01', '2024-01-01',  '2024-01-02', '2024-01-02', '2024-01-02', '2024-01-02', '2024-01-02', '2024-01-02', '2024-01-02'],
                   'area': [100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100],
                   'price': [10000000, 10000000, 10000000, 10000000, 10000000, 12000000, 12000000, 11080000, 11090000, 10000000, 10000000, 10000000, 12000000, 12000000],
                   'price_yest': [10000000, 10000000, 10000000, 10000000, 10000000, 12000000, 12000000, 10000000, 10000000, 10000000, 10000000, 10000000, 12000000, 12000000],
                   'status': ['cur', 'cur', 'cur', 'cur', 'cur', 'nf_sale', 'nf_sale', 'cur', 'cur', 'cur', 'sold', 'sold', 'new', 'new']})
```

I need to calculate the price per square meter change from one day to the previous and the influence of each factor on this change.

Influencing factors:

1. Price change by premises
2. Add new premises
3. Sale

Rule for calculate:

- To calculate the average price per square meter, only current (`cur`)
  and new premises (`new`) are taken every day.
- Premises that were
  not for sale (`nf_sale`) can be added and then become (`new`)
- Sold (`sold`) premises are not taken into account in the price calculation

Desired result:

```
     date      area price       avg      avg/avg_yest  by_price_change by_new_premises  by_sale
0   2024-01-01  500 50000000    100000.0    0.0000         0.00              0.00     0.0000
1   2024-01-02  500 56170000    112340.0    0.1234         0.05          0.04     0.0334
```

I will be grateful for any help!

Comment: What is `price_yest`?

Comment: price yesterday

Comment: Why the area is `500`? Can you please [edit] your question and break the calculation in detail?

Comment: Cause we sum area by premises with statuses current and new

Answer (score 1):

I wrote an example:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# Create the dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame({'num': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7],
                   'date': ['2024-01-01', '2024-01-01', '2024-01-01', '2024-01-01', '2024-01-01', '2024-01-01', '2024-01-01',  '2024-01-02', '2024-01-02', '2024-01-02', '2024-01-02', '2024-01-02', '2024-01-02', '2024-01-02'],
                   'area': [100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100],
                   'price': [10000000, 10000000, 10000000, 10000000, 10000000, 12000000, 12000000, 11080000, 11090000, 10000000, 10000000, 10000000, 12000000, 12000000],
                   'price_yest': [10000000, 10000000, 10000000, 10000000, 10000000, 12000000, 12000000, 10000000, 10000000, 10000000, 10000000, 10000000, 12000000, 12000000],
                   'status': ['cur', 'cur', 'cur', 'cur', 'cur', 'nf_sale', 'nf_sale', 'cur', 'cur', 'cur', 'sold', 'sold', 'new', 'new']})

# Convert date to datetime for operations
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])

# Filter out only 'cur' and 'new' for calculation
df_filtered = df[df['status'].isin(['cur', 'new'])]

# Calculate the daily total price and total area
daily_totals = df_filtered.groupby('date').agg({'area': 'sum', 'price': 'sum'}).reset_index()

# Calculate average price per square meter
daily_totals['avg'] = daily_totals['price'] / daily_totals['area']

# Calculate change in average price per square meter
daily_totals['avg_change'] = daily_totals['avg'].pct_change()
daily_totals['avg_change'] = daily_totals['avg_change'].fillna(0)

# Random for by_price_change, by_new_premises, by_sale
daily_totals['by_price_change'] = np.random.rand(len(daily_totals)) * 0.1
daily_totals['by_new_premises'] = np.random.rand(len(daily_totals)) * 0.1
daily_totals['by_sale'] = np.random.rand(len(daily_totals)) * 0.1

print(daily_totals)
```

Comment: I print random cause I don't know correct values. it is necessary to find out how much each factor influenced the final price change.

Comment: If you have specific logic, I might be able to help you improve the code.